# Unable to move launchers for bash scripts onto 'favorites' on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: icons, ubuntu-dock

Just upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04. On 16.04, I had a lot of shortcuts with custom icons on 'Launcher' for quick access.
After the upgrade, all the icons are changed to standard text (?) icons and I'm unable to move them to 'Favorites' which seems to have replaced the 'Launcher' on 18.04. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I moved the `.desktop` files from `~/Desktop/` to `~/.local/share/applications/`

Everything works now.